# SQuirreL won't launch

Tags: command-line, software-installation, java

I'm trying to run [SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) on Ubuntu 18.04 but I'm not able to make it launch.

When I run

```
~/squirrel-sql-3.8.1/squirrel-sql.sh
```

Nothing happens. I don't understand the sh script very well.  I tried just running:

```
java -cp squirrel-sql.jar:~/squirrel/sql-3.8.1/lib* -splash:~/squirrel-sql-3.8.1/icons/splash.jpg net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main --squirrel-home "~/squirrel-sql-3.8.1"
```

But it then says

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no splashscreen in java.library.path
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2541)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:873)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1857)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:134)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:132)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(SplashScreen.java:131)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.SquirrelSplashScreen.<init>(SquirrelSplashScreen.java:37)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Application.startup(Application.java:219)
```

My Java version:

```
openjdk version 9-Ubuntu
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu=0-9b181-4, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Ubuntu 17.10 has crossed [EOL](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle), please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Melebius upgrade to 18.04 done.  The issue remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted out.

I upgraded to Java 10 via:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk
```

Now Java version reads:

```
openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Enviornment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server (buidl 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

And now the application launches.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the error i got when i tried to run `squirrel-sql.sh`. I had installed headless jdk hich as causing the issue.

Error :

```
sourabh@phoenix:~/squirrel-sql-4.1.0-standard$ ./squirrel-sql.sh 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no splashscreen in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
    ...........
```

Uninstall Headless Java JDK :

```
sourabh@phoenix:~/squirrel-sql-4.1.0-standard$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Install Java JDL :

```
sourabh@phoenix:~/squirrel-sql-4.1.0-standard$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8
```